# Firebase push notification send extra data from a model class

Tags: java, android, firebase

I was using FirebaseMessagingService to send a notification to other users using my app, the problem is I cannot add extra data to the message. I have a notification, sender, and data model classes. Problem is when I try adding the data model when sending the token however I get invalid JSON.

**Notifcation class:**

```
    public String title;
    public String body;


    public Notification() {
    }

    public Notification(String title, String body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

**Sender class:**

```
public class Sender {

    public Notification data;
    public data extra;
    public String to;

    public Sender() {
    }

    public Sender(Notification data, data extra, String to) {
        this.data = data;
        this.to = to;
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    public Notification getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Notification data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

**data class:**

```
public class data {

    public String username;

    public data() {
    }

    public data(String username) {
        this.username = username;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**Home:**

```
                    data extra = new data("Test");
                    Notification notification = new Notification("title test", "body test");
                    Sender content = new Sender(notification, extra, token.getToken());

                    mService.sendMessage(content)
                            .enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponse> call, Response<FCMResponse> response) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                                    if (response.body().success == 1){
                                        Toast.makeText(c, "Request sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(c, "Request failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<FCMResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: "+ t.getMessage());
                                }
                            });
```

**MyFirebaseMessaingService:**

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       if (remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty()){

       } else {
            String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title").toString();
            String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body").toString();
            String username = remoteMessage.getData().get("username").toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "showNotifcation: " + title + body + username);
       }
    }
```

Problem occurs when i send extra data from the model class i.e the username. Without send extra data i.e just the notification it will work fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want to make the client be able to send notifications? What if someone reverse engineers your keys?

Comment: for now its just a test app so no real users data will be published into it